# Problems getting gitlab to use AWS object storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab

I'm trying to set up a docker-hosted Gitlab CE instance with all data stored in AWS. I've set up a postgres database and S3 buckets and tested connectivity to both from the docker host. I've configured gitlab with connection details and can see postgres chatter happily flowing and it's created a bunch of database tables successfully.

However, I cannot see any HTTPS traffic to s3 endpoints and, as far as I can tell, if I create a repo and upload a file, it ends up in the docker volume. I can't spot anything obviously wrong in the logs. Cloudtrail only shows my test connection with the same authentication details as gitlab is configured with.

Here's the relevant config section, have I done anything stupid? Anything in particular I should look at to get any clues?

```
gitlab_rails['object_store']['enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {
  'provider'                => 'AWS',
  'aws_access_key_id'       => 'xxxx',
  'aws_secret_access_key'   => 'xxxx',
  'region'                  => 'eu-west-1',
  'host'                    => 's3.amazonaws.com'
}
gitlab_rails['object_store']['proxy_download'] = true
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['artifacts']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-artifacts'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['external_diffs']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-externaldiffs'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['lfs']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-lfs'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['uploads']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-uploads'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['packages']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-packages'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['dependency_proxy']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-dependencyproxy'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['terraform_state']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-terraformstate'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['ci_secure_files']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-cisecurefiles'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['pages']['bucket'] = 'xxx-gitlab-pages'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems I hadn't done anything wrong. I had incorrectly assumed that ALL data could be stored in an object store but that's not correct (not trivially, anyway).

Yes, some data can be stored in S3 but not the repo data itself. Inside the container, it's Gitaly that manages the back-end data for the repositories an there's no support for S3, etc..

Instead, I'll opt for running the docker container on an S3 instance and mount a volume for the repo data (/var/opt/gitlab inside container). I'll take scheduled EBS snapshots for DR.

Ideally, I'd go for a full load-balanced HA Gitlab cluster but that's overkill for current requirements.